# How do I enable webGL 2.0 API libs in emsripten C++?

Tags: emscripten, webgl2

I am working on trying to get the webGL2.0 features working with emscripten C++ program, and for now running on the latest firefox nightly.

I am trying to test using a GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER object and hopefully make it shared by several shader programs.

I set the flag -s USE_WEBGL2=1 on the compiler and it all compiles as it enables the headers.  But I get link errors.

```
warning: undefined symbol: glBindBufferBase
warning: undefined symbol: glGetActiveUniformBlockiv
warning: undefined symbol: glGetActiveUniformsiv
warning: undefined symbol: glGetUniformBlockIndex
warning: undefined symbol: glGetUniformIndices
```

How do I link these and the other symbols I need ? Are they not available ? Is this the wrong API? Do I need to create bindings for them to javascript ?  Is there another flag I need to set ? etc ???

do I need to use glew ? special ways to use it in enscripten ?

frustrated ...

I am including these headers from the "emsdk" include folder.

```
#ifdef __EMSCRIPTEN__ // defined by emscripten compiler/'os'
    #include <emscripten.h>
    #include <emscripten/html5.h>
    #include <GLES3/gl3.h>
    #include <GLES3/gl2ext.h>
#else
```

I have not called any gl functions directly to javascript yet. Is this what I need to do ?

Comment: Does WebGL2 run on your machine in general? (in JavaScript, not via emscripten). Have you tried finding a working sample?  The source to the GL emulation is [here](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/blob/incoming/src/library_gl.js) and all of those functions are defined. I just tried adding a call to `glBindBufferBase` in [my own sample](https://github.com/greggman/doodles/tree/master/glfw-imgui) though I'm using a modified version of the library but no modified in anyway that would affect those functions. (wanted a hook to modify shader source so I didn't have to change the code from GL3)

Comment: @gman so for the emscripten build did you have to include anything else than the -s USE_WEBGL2=1 flag fpr the javascript genration phase? what C++ headers did you include ? I updated the question.  In what way did you modify the library ? and which one ?

Comment: see the [build.sh](https://github.com/greggman/doodles/blob/master/glfw-imgui/build.sh) in that folder. I modified `glShaderSource` to replace `#verision xxx` with `#version 300 es` in `library_gl.js` and I modified `library_glfw.js` to so that I could set a render function with `glfwSetWindowRefreshCallback` and request it with `glfwMarkWindowForRefresh`. Otherwise you have to compile your mainloop to be interpreted . See [https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/porting/emscripten-runtime-environment.html#browser-main-loop]

Comment: @gman will try that when I get the current obsessive bit done :) thanks.

Comment: @gman on the main loop does that work only for full screen" I want to take over the browser situations or is it just to use the glfw api?

Comment: I haven't tried using the fullscreen API via glfw but if [you look in the code](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/blob/incoming/src/library_glfw.js) it looks like it's hooked up